# SQL insert with oop validation

Tags: php, pdo

I had been slowly learning PHP OOP, I decided it was time to start inserting into my table, however it doesn't seem to be inserting. I compared my code with working versions and I can't see what the problem might be, I attempted a var_dump(), the query returned as I expected, I tested my database class by creating an new user, it was successfully created so I assume it isn't that, I tested the SQL query and it was able to insert, I'm at a loss for it might be now

form

```
<?php 
 session_start(); 
require ("classes/Review.php");
require ("classes/Database.php");

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        $reviewing = new ReviewValidation();
        $review = $reviewTitle = "";
        $post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);     

        $reviewTitle = $post['reviewTitle'];
        $review =  $post['review'];     
        $errors = array();

        $fields = array(
        'title' => array(        
            'validate' => 'title',
            'message' => 'Title must be at least fife characters',
            'value' => $reviewTitle,
        ),
        'review' => array(         
            'validate' => 'review',
            'message' => 'Your review must be at least three hundred characters',
            'value' => $review,
        )
        );

        foreach($fields as $key => $value) 
        {
            $validation_result = $reviewing->{$value['validate']}($value['value']);
            if(!$validation_result) 
            {
                $errors[] = ['name' => $key, 'error' => $value['message']];
            }
        }

        if(empty($errors))  
        {  
            try
            {
            $db = new Database;
            $success = ["message" => "Review subbbmitted"];     
            $process = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO reviews (reviewTitle)
            VALUES
            (:reviewTitle');
            $process->bindValue(':reviewTitle', $reviewTitle);
            $process->execute();

            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                $errors[] = ['response' => 'fail'];  
            } 
        }
    }

header('Content-Type: application/json');
if (empty($errors))
{
    echo json_encode($success);
}
else
{
    echo json_encode(["errors" => $errors]);
}
```

class

```
<?php 

class ReviewValidation
{
    private
    $db,
    $review,
    $reviewTitle;

    private static
    $reviewLength = 50,
    $rewviewtitleLength = 5;

    public static function title($reviewTitle)
    {
        return(strlen($reviewTitle) >= self::$rewviewtitleLength);
    }

    public static function review($review)
    {
            return(strlen($review) >= self::$reviewLength);
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the error you getting ?

Comment: "var_dump(), the query returned as I expected"  A `var_dump()` of _what_? And what exactly was the result that you say was expected?

Comment: `object(PDOStatement)#4 (1) {
  ["queryString"]=>
  string(62) "INSERT INTO reviews (reviewTitle)
   VALUES
   (:reviewTitle"
}
{"message":"Review subbbmitted"}`

Comment: No error message that I can see at least, if there was one I could at least search online for that

Comment: What is returned by `execute`? If false check `errorCode` / `errorInfo`. Probably look at `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` also (fits your code, which by the way looks fine).

Comment: That is a nice way to catch errors, `Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'review' doesn't have a default value{"message":"Review subbbmitted"}`

Comment: You need to either provide a value to your fields during the insert or they need to have default values in the table definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you may be missing the closing ) in the insert query:

```
$process = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO reviews (reviewTitle)
        VALUES
        (:reviewTitle)');
```

If you add in a closing parenthesis after :reviewTitle, before the single quote your syntax will be correct (shown above).

I also noticed that your calls to the static methods in the ReviewValidation class are using the object operator (->).  To access static methods you need to utilize the [scope resolution operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php).

So your $validation_result line should look like:

```
$validation_result = ReviewValidation::{$value['validate']}($value['value']);
```

I think because of this, the validation may have been passing, which is why you where getting the no default value issue.